# Purpose and Name of this Sequence

Tags: binary-tree

C(n)=  2nCn * 1/(n+1)

The above sequence is used to find the possible no. of binary search trees, I want to know that what is the name of above sequence and the purposes for which this sequence can be used efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

The name is Catalan Equation (Sequence).

I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352776/the-possible-number-of-binary-search-trees-that-can-be-created-with-n-keys-is-giv) contains the information you want.

Comment: But I want to know what are the various places where this catalan sequence is efficiently used, any e.g. would be gratefull