# Relationship between following two recursive methods which generates balanced paranthesized strings (Catalan Number)?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have some understanding of Catalan numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and their applications (for ex, generating balanced parenthesized strings, balanced strings from given n+1 factors etc. I am using below two methods to generate balanced parenthesized strings. One basically uses Catalan recursive formula and another is nothing but a simple recursive function which ensures the number of left parenthesis always greater than or equal to right parenthesis. I understand why both generate correct strings and why the total number of such strings are nothing but Catalan Number.

**Question:**

However I am unable to understand relationship between these two approaches (algorithms)? Does the second approach also satisfy **Catalan recursive relationship** as the first one, but implicitly? if yes, can anyone please explain in words as I am having hard time coming up with that explanation...

Basically I am looking for some explanation in words rather than mathematically - as with first approach I can clearly see it satisfies Catalan Relationship, but not with the second one.  And also please note that I am not looking for difference in efficiencies like the first one recalculating sub problems, extra space etc. - **focus is only on relating the second recursion with Cartisan recursive relationship**.

Related but not same as the question is not about solving them, rather difference and explanation of difference, and relating both to Cartisan recursive relationship:
[Valid Permutation of Parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172179/valid-permutation-of-parenthesis)
[The possible number of binary search trees that can be created with N keys is given by the Nth catalan number. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352776/the-possible-number-of-binary-search-trees-that-can-be-created-with-n-keys-is-giv)

**Appraoch 1 (using Catalan Relationship)**

```
string[] CatalanNumber_AllPossibleParanthesis(int N)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(N >= 0);
            if(N==0)
            {
                return new string[] {" "};
            }
            if(N == 1)
            {
                return new string[] { "[]" };
            }

            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= (N - 1); i++)
            {
                var r1 = this.CatalanNumber_AllPossibleParanthesis(i);
                var r2 = this.CatalanNumber_AllPossibleParanthesis(N - 1 - i);

                foreach (var s1 in r1)
                {
                    foreach (var s2 in r2)
                    {
                        //[c']c" - will be of the form
                        string r = "[" + s1.Trim() + "]" + s2.Trim();
                        results.Add(r);
                    }
                }
            }
            return results.ToArray();
        }
```

**Approach 2 (with smple recursion by making sure #left ( >= #right**

```
string[] GetAllPossibleParanthesis_2(int left, int right, string s)
        {
            if((left == 0) && (right==0))
            {
                return new string[] { s };
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(left <= right);
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            if (left > 0)
            {
                var r = this.GetAllPossibleParanthesis_2(left - 1, 
                    right, s + "[");
                results.AddRange(r);
            }
            if(left <= (right-1))
            {
                var r = this.GetAllPossibleParanthesis_2(left,
                    right-1, s + "]");
                results.AddRange(r);
            }
            return results.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Try to list all the interim steps for both algorithms as they build the strings for the first few N's (N = 1 to 3, maybe 4,5). I suspect the recursions perform similar string-building activities. Either way, it might be an illuminating, if a little tedious, task.