# Why the formula to calculate number of combinations for binary tree is (2*n)fact / (n)fact * (n+1)fact

Tags: math, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, discrete-mathematics

I know by the formula

`(2*n)!/n! * (n+1)!`

the number of possible Binary Tree Combinations can be found out.

eg. for n=3, 5 combinations are possible.

I also know [NCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) but the **standard formula** of NCR is `n!/r!(n-r)!`.

So I want to know why formula for Combinations of Possible Binary tree is `(2*n)!/n! * (n+1)!`. What is the derivation behind this formula, from where it came.

Comment: What is a "Binary Tree Combination"? What is an "NCR"?

Comment: PS: is this question related to your? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352776/the-possible-number-of-binary-search-trees-that-can-be-created-with-n-keys-is-gi

Comment: no, its a different question. And binary tree combinations is number of combinations/structures possible for n nodes

Comment: The wikipedia page you linked does not mention "Binary Tree Combination". But your question is to calculate the number of possible Binary Tree Combinations. So, I ask again: what is a "Binary Tree Combination"?

Comment: you can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042412/with-n-no-of-nodes-how-many-different-binary-and-binary-search-trees-possib

Comment: This is really a mathematics question, not a programming one. There are various different proofs of this result. (The search term you want is "Catalan number". The wikipedia page has several proofs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: I think this is the right stack exchange because mathamaticians may not know about data structures/binary trees

Comment: @sahilpahuja: I think you should test that hypothesis by posting on https://math.stackexchange.com. (And I think you'll find that there are plenty of mathematicians who know about Catalan numbers and binary trees.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about mathematics, not programming